# Swing : change the icon of jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

class Two {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));
        JFrame frmOne = new JFrame("FACEBOOK");
        frmOne.setIconImage(img);
        frmOne.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmOne.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In this code here, a JPG image is displayed instead of a `JFrame` icon. However, I want to know about the functionality of the line `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));`. Any help would be appreciated, I am new to swing.

Comment: 1) Please consult the JavaDocs for the initial explanations of these things. 2)  `framOne` has a bad smell about it.  There should never be a `framTwo`.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  3) That code will mot likely fail at time of deployment.  The image will become an embedded resource by then, and should be accessed by URL. 4) Honor the rules of the EDT!

Answer (score 4):

The code `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));` works as follows:

1. `BufferedImage img = ...` says the rest of the line should be stored to the variable.
2. `ImageIO.read(...` says read an image from given file
3. `new File("index.jpg")` says find the File named `"index.jpg"`

So overall, it loads an image out of the index.jpg file and stores this image into the `BufferedImage img`. You then later just call `frmOne.setIconImage(img)` which takes the image you read out of the file, and sets it to be the frame's icon.

Answer (score 3):

The `setIconImage` method changes the image icon that is displayed in the top left side of the `JFrame` and when switching between applications. Another choice is:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("filename").getImage());
```

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));`

Analysis:

- `BufferedImage img`

this creates a `BufferedImage` variable called `img`, We can think of this as an Object which holds the data needed for java to display an image, a `BufferedImage` [as per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

> The `BufferedImage` subclass describes an `Image` with an accessible
>   buffer of image data. A `BufferedImage` is comprised of a `ColorModel` and
>   a Raster of image data.

- `ImageIO`

This class basically contains methods to help us read and write image without having to write our own each time, [As per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

> A class containing static convenience methods for locating
>   `ImageReaders` and `ImageWriters`, and performing simple encoding and
>   decoding.

- `read(File input)`

This is a `public` `static` method inside `ImageIO` thus can be accessed without the `new` keyword. It allows us to read in data of the file we want to use as a `Image` and returns the data it read in (thus we save it in a variable) as [per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29):

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with
>   an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently
>   registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream.
>
> Parameters: input - a File to read from.
>
> Returns: a BufferedImage containing the decoded contents of the input, or null.
>
> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if input is null. IOException - if an error
>   occurs during reading.

- `new File(String filename)`

is a non static method in the class [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and thus has to be accessed with a newly created instance (`new`). It allows us to create a reference to the file, so that we can perform operations on the `File` instance (i.e reading writing etc) [as per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29):

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
>
> Parameters: pathname - A pathname string
>
> Throws: NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

Now when you call `setIconImage(img)` all the data we read from the file (which is our picture and was converted to an `BufferedImage`) will be used to display the picture as the `JFrame`s Icon.

Another way to do it is:

```
// Create frame
String title = "Frame Title";
JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

// Set icon
Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.gif");
frame.setIconImage(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to mention that you'll have to handle an exception.  IMHO, the code might be better written as so:

```
BufferedImage img = null;  

try {
  img = ImageIO.read(new File("youricon.png"));   // get icon for JFrame
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} 

frame.setIconImage(img);                          // set JFrame icon
```

Also, as you read the docs take note that .ico files are not handled by ImageIO().  Use .jpg, .png, .bmp or .gif files.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html for further information.

HTH